# Web scraping articles using asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, asyncio

I use asyncio to speed up web scraping. I collect only title, author, tags, datetime, total comments from list view from specific [website](https://unboxholics.com/news). Also, i collect these from all pages.
I would like to improve my code, so any idea i would appreciate it.

My code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from functools import reduce
from operator import iconcat

@dataclass
class Article:
    title: str
    author: str
    tags: str
    upload_on: str
    comments: int
    link: str

    @classmethod
    def from_page_items(cls, item: Tag) -> 'Article':
        spans = item.find('div', {'class': 'entry__header'}).find_all('span')
        entry_title = item.find('h2', {'class': 'entry__title'})
        anchor = item.find('div', {'class': 'entry__header'}).find_all('a')

        return cls(
            title=entry_title.text.strip(),
            author=anchor[1].text,
            tags=anchor[2].text,
            upload_on=spans[0].text,
            comments=int(spans[1].text) if len(spans) > 1 else 0,
            link=entry_title.find('a').get('href')
        )


class Scrape:

    def __init__(self, url) -> None:
        self.session = None
        self.url = url

    async def __aenter__(self):
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *args):
        await self.session.close()

    async def fetch_url(self, params: dict = {}) -> BeautifulSoup:
        """Fetch a url and return HTML document

        Args:
            params (dict, optional): [description]. Defaults to {}.

        Returns:
            BeautifulSoup: HTML document
        """
        async with self.session.get(self.url, params=params) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            resp_text = await response.text()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(resp_text, 'html.parser')
        return soup

    async def get_page_articles(self, page: int) -> List[Article]:
        """For each page return all the articles in a list contain details with Article Class

        Args:
            page (int): the number of page

        Returns:
            List[Article]: List of Article
        """
        doc = await self.fetch_url(params={'p': page})
        articles = [Article.from_page_items(article) for article in doc.findAll(
            'article', {'class': 'entry card post-list'})]
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return articles

    async def gather_articles(self) -> List[List[Article]]:
        """Gather all pages until the end of pagination `end_page`

        Returns:
            List[List[Article]]
        """
        doc = await self.fetch_url(self.url)
        end_page_number = doc.select_one(
            'ul.pagination li:last-child').find('a')['href'].split('=')[-1]
        coros = [self.get_page_articles(page) for page in range(1, end_page_number + 1)]
        return await asyncio.gather(*coros)

    async def get_all_articles(self) -> List[Article]:
        """Gather all articles and transform to List[Article]
        Returns:
            List[Article]
        """
        result = await self.gather_articles()
        return reduce(iconcat, result, [])



async def main():
    async with Scrape(BASE_URL) as scrape:
        result = await scrape.get_all_articles()
        print(result)

asyncio.run(main())
```

After that, using this code, i will store all the info into a database and play with pandas library.